# How to prove that, if matrix $A$ is unipotent, then the characteristic polynomial satisfies $c_A(Z) = (1-Z)^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am working on the following Algebra past paper problem:

A matrix $A$ is called unipotent if $A - I$ is nilpotent.
Using the Cayley-Hamilton theorem or otherwise, prove that $A$ is unipotent if and only if $c_A(Z) = (1-Z)^n$.

My working so far:

Let $B = A - I$.

By the definition of a nilpotent matrix, the only eigenvalue of $B$ is $Z = 0$.

It follows that $\det(B - ZI_n) = Z^n$.

I then tried to use the fact that $c_B(B) = 0$ (by Cayley-Hamilton).
I.e., $c_{A-I_n}(A - I_n) = 0$.
Since $c_B(Z) = 0$ is satisfied only by $Z = 0$, it follows that $A - I_n = 0$ and so $A = I_n$.
Therefore, $\det(A-ZI_n) = \det((1-Z)I_n) = (1 - Z)^n$.

I would appreciate any **corrections** to my working and any **hints** for a potentially more convincing first part to the proof!

Answer (score 1):

$\lambda \in \text{Spec} (A-I ) \iff 1 + \lambda \in \text{Spec} (A)$.
It follows that $ C_{A-I}(x)=\prod(x-\lambda_{i})$ and $C_{A}(x) = \prod (x-(1 +\lambda_{
i}))$. Since $A-I$ is nilpotent, $ \lambda_{i} =0$ and the result drops out.

Comment: How exactly does the result follow, though?  Since $\lambda_i = 0$, we get that $C_A(x) = \prod(x - 1) = (x - 1)^n$.  Is this equal to $(1 - x)^n$, the result that I want to show?

Comment: It is a matter of how you write a characteristic polynomial $C_{A}(x) = \det(xI - A) = (-1)^{n}\det (A - xI)$. You see how I started with $B = A - I$, to get your result, you could apply the same logic to $I - A$.